# How to store my JWT token correctly and return data in MERN app

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, client, mern

I'm creating a MERN application as I'm learning how to use React to create a blog/social media like website. I already have routes and jsx setup in order to display posts via axios requests and pulling the data from my MongoDB cluster.

This all works perfectly but I am now struggling on finding a proper way to handle authentication for users and display data back into my MERN application.
My current code that registers the user takes their name, email and password; using bcrpyt to hash/salt the password for security.

Register Code

```
exports.register = (req, res, next) => {
   let {
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password_confirmation
   } = req.body;
   User.findOne({
         email: email
      })
      .then(user => {
         if (user) {
            return res.status(422).json({
               errors: [{
                  user: "email already exists"
               }]
            });
         } else {
            const user = new User({
               name: name,
               email: email,
               password: password,
            });
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
               bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                  if (err) throw err;
                  user.password = hash;
                  user.save()
                     .then(response => {
                        res.status(200).json({
                           success: true,
                           result: response
                        })
                     })
                     .catch(err => {
                        res.status(500).json({
                           errors: [{
                              error: err
                           }]
                        });
                     });
               });
            });
         }
      }).catch(err => {
         res.status(500).json({
            errors: [{
               error: 'Something went wrong'
            }]
         });
      })
}
```

my login function then uses bcrypt.compare in order to make sure the password types in matches with the hashed password stored in the database. If succesful, my code will call a function I created called createJWT which has a payload containing the email, userId and duration of the token before expiring.

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

exports.createJWT = (email, userId, duration) => {
    const payload = {
        email,
        userId,
        duration
    };

    return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: duration,
    });
};
```

Login code

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
   let {
      email,
      password
   } = req.body;
   User.findOne({
      email: email
   }).then(user => {
      if (!user) {
         return res.status(404).json({
            errors: [{
               user: "not found"
            }],
         });
      } else {
         bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
            if (!isMatch) {
               return res.status(400).json({
                  errors: [{
                     password: "incorrect"
                  }]
               });
            }
            let access_token = createJWT(
               user.email,
               user._id,
               3600
            );
            jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err,
               decoded) => {
               if (err) {
                  res.status(500).json({
                     errors: err
                  });
               }
               if (decoded) {
                  return res.status(200).json({
                     success: true,
                     token: access_token,
                     message: user
                  });
               }
            });
         }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
               errors: err
            });
         });
      }
   }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({
         errors: err
      });
   });
}
```

If the login function is succesful, the code will decode the JWT code if the token matches my TOKEN_SECRET stored in my env file.

This all works perfectly fine but I am stuck at this point on where to go next. I have created a piece of middleware that I can succesfully implement into my routes in order to stop them loading if the user is not authorized.

```
//Auth middleware

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: "Token not authorized!"
        })
    }
};


const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require("multer");
const authorize = require('../middleware/auth');


const {
    getPosts,
    createPost,
    findPostById,
    updatePost,
    deletePost
} = require('../controllers/posts');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, './client/public/uploads');
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
});

router.get('/', authorize, getPosts);
router.post('/add', upload.single("postImage"), createPost);
router.get('/:id', findPostById);
router.put('/update/:id', upload.single("postImage"), updatePost);
router.delete('/:id', deletePost);


module.exports = router;
```

From this point, what would be the best way to have the user login and gain access to the posts (containing my authorization middleware) if they have logged in succesfully and have the JWT token. I was also wondering how i would achieve something like pulling the users name from the decoded token and have it shown (for example) in the navbar for as long as they logged in / the session persists.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let access_token = createJWT(
               user.email,
               user._id,
               3600
            );
            jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, (err,
               decoded) => {
               if (err) {
                  res.status(500).json({
                     errors: err
                  });
               }
               if (decoded) {
                  return res.status(200).json({
                     success: true,
                     token: access_token,
                     message: user
                  });
               }
            });
```

There's no point to verify the JWT here as you just generated it on the server-side. This is the process:

1. Register: The user provides a username and a password. You save the user in the database and for the password, you save a hash.
2. When logging in, the user is providing the username and the password. If they are correct you create a JWT and return that to the client application. In the JWT you will encode the username/user_id.
3. The client needs to store that JWT somewhere and then send it in the following requests(usually as a header).
4. On the server you have a middleware that parses that header, decodes the JWT, and identify the user based on username/user_id or whatever you encoded there.

The client should not decode the JWT and pull information like the username from there. It should make an API request to the backend asking for the user information.

There are lots of things to take into consideration here like. Just to name a few:

- how do you store the JWT on the client in a secure way?
- on the client app, how do you prevent an unauthenticated user to access some private routes?
- what do you do after the JWT expires?
- how do you handle CORS?
- are there any vulnerabilities?

I highly recommend this [free course](https://reactsecurity.io/) which will teach you a lot about how to implement these things.